# SharePoint 2010 error not found in logs, how to configure logging?

Tags: logging

We have a SharePoint 2010 feature that works fine on my development machine, but won't activate on the staging system. It's SiteCollection scoped, the containing solution was successfully deployed on one WebApplication.

When we try to activate the feature, **we get an error message with a Correlation ID. But we can't find this ID or the name of the feature in the SharePoint Logs nor in the Windows Event Log.**

Maybe logging wasn't configured right or there is an error with ULS on the machine, but we haven't changed the SharePoint Logging options from the state they were after installation. Where can I find exception / error messages that happen in ULS? How must Logging be configured to allow the failed feature activation to be logged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple servers make sure you either check each of the servers or use the following powershell function to extract the error.

Get-SPLogEvent |
?{$_.Correlation -eq ""} |
ft Category, Message -Autosize

Here is a great post from Wictor on the logs:  http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Working-with-SharePoint-2010-Correlation-ID-in-PowerShell-and-code.aspx

Comment: Thx, we tried Get-SPLogEvent and Merge-SPLogFile, but couldn't find anything for the Correlation ID ...

Comment: I have seen the same behaviour when for example Organization mapping failed with correlation ID in Central admin. There were no trace of it in the log files either..

Comment: Hi, now I've found the log message in the log file on another one of the frontend servers. Somehow Get-SPLogEvent and Merge-SPLogFile couldn't find it. If you have a PowerShell example to successful search the logs from all frontends, I would happily accept your answer.

Comment: Same here did not find the proper correlation ID

Answer (score 0):

In Central Administration, you can set the level (Error, Info, Debug, None, etc.) of the errors to be logged.

Comment: I've tried to set both of the dropdown boxes to verbose ... but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the account for application pools to the “Performance Log Users” group, after that make IISRESET.

1. http://www.eiben.weite-welt.com/2011/08/no-uls-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/
2. http://kollegaru.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/no-errors-in-uls-logs-with-defined-correllation-id-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB/